# Missing attachments when parse .p7m file

Tags: java, certificate, jakarta-mail, exchangewebservices

> I have a [p7m](http://1drv.ms/1lZqKzm) file in my disk which contains 1 jpg picture, 1 txt file and a email body context. Fortunately, I can get the email body text and the p7s file. I can verify the p7s file(certificate), but I can not find the two attachments. It looks like missing. I don't know why? Anyone has meet this issue?
>   And the p7m file is from EWS(Outlook).

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
  DataSource source = new FileDataSource("C:/Users/zhontao/Desktop/smime.p7m");
  MimeMultipart multi1 = new MimeMultipart(source);
  for (int i = 0; i < multi1.getCount(); i++) {
    Part part1 = multi1.getBodyPart(i);
    if (part1.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
      Multipart multi2 = (Multipart) part1.getContent();
      for (int j = 0; j < multi2.getCount(); j++) {
        Part part2 = multi2.getBodyPart(i);
        String contentType = part2.getContentType();
        System.out.println(contentType);
        // generally if the content type multipart/alternative, it is email text.
        if (part2.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) {
          if (part2.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
            Multipart multi3 = (Multipart) part2.getContent();
            for (int k = 0; k < multi3.getCount(); k++) {
              Part part4 = multi3.getBodyPart(k);
              String contentType1 = part4.getContentType();
              System.out.println(contentType1);
              if (part4.isMimeType("text/plain") && !Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part4.getDisposition())) {
                System.out.println(part4.getContent().toString());
              } else if (part4.isMimeType("text/html") && !Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part4.getDisposition())) {
                System.out.println(part4.getContent().toString());
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      String contentType = part1.getContentType();
      System.out.println(contentType);
      String disposition = part1.getDisposition();
      System.out.println(disposition);
      System.out.println(part1.getFileName());
      // this.saveFile(part1.getFileName(), part1.getInputStream());
    }
  }
} catch (MessagingException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Part part2 = multi2.getBodyPart(i);
```

should be

```
Part part2 = multi2.getBodyPart(j);
```